# How to constrain by country using Google Places API textSearch?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, geocoding

Currently the Google Places API does not support `componentRestrictions`, so you are not able to constrain a Places API search to a specific country. This can create all sorts of unexpected behavior, such as searching for "rivervale" being found in the US (River Vale) instead of Singapore (Rivervale) (see [Codepen](http://codepen.io/thdoan/pen/LNazwg)).

My current solution is to rely on region biasing by appending the country to the search string (e.g., "rivervale singapore"). However, this method is also not fool-proof as any location that has the name of the country in its name can also turn up in the results outside of the intended country.

Is there another way to reliably contrain a Places API search to find only locations within a specified country?

UPDATE: I'm aware that you can add `componentRestrictions` via the Place Autocomplete widget, e.g.:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'SG'
  }
}
```

This does constrain the autocomplete drop-down list to find Rivervale within Singapore, but if the user presses Enter without selecting from the autocomplete list, then the marker for River Vale in the US gets returned instead.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to restrict places search to certain country at the moment. You can bias results to certain area specifying location and radius parameters.

Comment: @xomena thanks for the comment. Do you know if the GMaps team is planning to add this ability in the near future?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know.